# Where should I add servlets in the Eclipse IDE's new folder structure

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, project-structure

I'm new to dynamic web designing using java. In the reference video I'm following the professor is using an older version of eclipse IDE. My folder structure is a bit different from his. I'm using tomcat version 9 and I'm supposed to use MVC architecture. Can someone please let me know where should I save the servlets in the new folder structure?
I'm using the following version of the Eclipse IDE.
Version: 2021-09 (4.21.0)
The image attached to this contains my folder structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *"new"* default folder structure, introduced in WTP 3.21 (Eclipse 2021-03, cf. [release notes](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.21/NewAndNoteworthy/#Modernized%20default%20paths)) follows [Maven conventions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), therefore:

1. the folder `/src/main/java` is a source folder and contains Java sources. Here you should put your servlets. The contents of this folder are compiled into the `WEB-INF/classes` folder of the WAR file,
2. the folder `/src/main/resources` contains files that need to be in the classpath, but are not compiled. This is also mapped into the `WEB-INF/classes` folder of the WAR file,
3. the folder `/src/main/webapp` is the root folder of the WAR file (replaces the `/WebContent` folder). Here (and in its subfolders) you'll usually put JSPs and static web resources.